# How to access `with`-context from other scope in Python?

Tags: python, with-statement, tqdm

I have a `with`-statement like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(documents) as progress_bar:
    for document in documents:
        if [...]:
            process(document)
            progress_bar.update()
```

`process()` is another function, in which I would like to condition the logging on whether there is a `tqdm` instance in the context (called from the above code) or not (called from somewhere else). In pseudo-code e.g.:

```
def process(document):
     if <tqdm in context>:
       progress_bar.write("processing")
     else:
       logging.info("processing")
```

Can I dynamically find and access a `with`-context (provided by `tqdm` in this example) from a parent scope? How?

The [`contextlib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/contextlib.html) does not offer a (straight-forward) way for accessing a `with`-context.

The workaround I have found so far was to pass the `progress_bar` object as an optional parameter to `process()`, and use it if available. However, it seems potentially redundant to change the function just for this purpose.

Does Python in general, or `tqdm` specifically, provide a pattern for handling this?

**Update for background**:

The use case here is that in the real-world code here, I have a concatenation of function calls. `process()` is in fact more complex and calls various other functions. These might log output, which should go to `progress_bar.write()` if available.

If the leaf function in the call stack cannot access the `with`-context from the root function, I need to pass the `progress_bar` object down through all levels in the call tree.

Comment: Explicitly pass the object. Period. A function should act explicitly on its inputs. As soon as you go down the path of using some implicit environmental conditions in your function it becomes extremely hard to reason about and maintain it.

Comment: @deceze I think you are right in principle. Only counter-argument is what I have now added to the question: there is a chain of function calls, so I would have to pass the object through all of them.

Comment: Possibly redesign this to always pass that argument as something like `progress: Callable[[str], Any] = logging.info`…? I.e., instead of an `if..else`, you just have `progress('processing')`, and the higher up caller cares about where that should write to. If that's several levels up, well, so be it. Maybe you need to think about using a class instead which accepts this as constructor argument and can share it among all its member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- There is no way to implicitly access a `with`-context in another function (and there should not be).
- The best and cleanest solution is to explicitly pass the object to use for writing. For the given use case, you can/should use a default value like this:

```
def process(document, writer: Callable[[str], Any] = logging.info):
    writer("processing")    
    [...]
```

In order to write to a `tqdm` instance instead of a logger, you can call `process()` like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(documents) as progress_bar:
    for document in documents:
        if [...]:
            process(document, writer=progress_bar.write)
            progress_bar.update()
```